# Why does adding one more extension cable turn the MCB on again?

Tags: power, circuit-breaker

I found a strange phenomena when I tried to use a metal cutter that consumes about 2000 watt.
See the following illustration.

[image: wiring diagram]

If I just use one extension cable, the MCB will trip when I turn on the cutter. However, if I add one more extension cable, everything is just fine (the MCB does not trip). It looks strange to me. Why does it happen?

Comment: You need a motor rated MCB instead of the current one (e.g. class B or C instead of class A)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The additional extension cord adds more resistance, reducing the inrush current.

The inrush current required to trip a 20A breaker instantly can be as much as 300A, though it's more likely to be about 150A. This means the resistance of the whole system is less than 0.8 ohms.  An extra hundred milliohms, as would be added by a 20 foot 14 AWG extension cord, would make a difference of tens of amps of inrush current.

Comment: IMHO, the resistance change should be negligible. Or it is related to inductance of the wound part of the extension cord?

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity The inrush current required to trip a 20A breaker instantly can be as much as 300A, though it's more likely to be about 150A. An extra hundred milliohms could make a difference of tens of amps of inrush current.

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity: You should always unroll extension cords all the way in use.

Comment: @JRE: Thank you for informing this. :-)

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity, see my answer to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/232510/73158 to understand why inductance is unlikely to be a problem.

Answer (score 5):

That would happen, should there be a ground fault in the cutter and a break in the ground wire of the second extension cable.

[image]

A short circuit between the winding and the body of the cutter would result in the fault current, passing through the ground wire to earth, causing the MCB to trip.

The MCB would not trip, when the second extension cable is added, should the ground wire in that be broken.

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand this answer. But +1.

Comment: My answer has been edited for clarity.